# Importing D3 in a JavaScript module via script tag

Tags: d3.js, es6-modules

When importing D3 in a JavaScript module via a script tag I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'd3' of undefined` error.

Having read that all main browsers now support JavaScript modules, I am trying to import my D3 code via a `<script type="module" src="network.js"></script>` tag as described here:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules

However, when I import D3 I receive the error:

```
d3.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'd3' of undefined
    at d3.js:5
    at d3.js:6
```

If I have an `index.html` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script type="module" src="network.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

With D3 v5.7.0 in the same directory and `network.js` simply containing:

```js
import * as d3 from "./d3.js";
```

or just

```js
import "./d3.js";
```

the above error is received.

I would expect the same behaviour found with CommonJS or AMD:

https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate/issues/45#issuecomment-329590699

Comment: What's in `d3.js`? You cannot just use the normal UMD bundle for this as it does not feature any ES6 exports.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [es6 module import of d3 4.x fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471651/es6-module-import-of-d3-4-x-fails)